# Three sticks, three squares

Tags: matches

[image]There are 5 squares in this puzzle as shown in picture  we have to pick only three match sticks resulting formation of  exactly 3 squares. which numbers of sticks should be removed from the formation nothing extra stick.

Comment: are there not 6 squares initially?

Comment: yes you are right they may be considered six including big square.but solution is only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can form exactly 3 squares by removing sticks number

> 4,5 and 7
>  This leaves three squares in a left right left pattern